# How to bind DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a OnChange event (C#)

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a standard `DataGridView`, and my last column is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.
I would like to add an event so that when the selected index of any of the rows in that column changes, an event is triggered and I save that data to db.

I'm struggling with this for an hour or so and couldn't find any event that would trigger this...

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you mean everytime user changes an item in the last column combobox, you want to save that row data to the database? If, so I think that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `EditingControlShowing` event of the `DataGridView` attach a method to the combobox `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

For example:

```
private void DGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  if (DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == comboColumnIndex && e.Control is ComboBox)
  {
    ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
  }
}
```

Now in the below method you can do whatever you want:

```
private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Do saving work here
}
```

Comment: please notice that this approach will cause multiple registration to this event !

every time the EditingControl is about to show, you will re-register to the event.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something on these lines
The combobox is an editing control, so

```
private void dg_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  if (dg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == [yourcolumnindex])
  {
    ComboBox cmbox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    cmbox.SelectedValueChanged -= new EventHandler(cmbox_SelectedValueChanged);
    cmbox.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(cmbox_SelectedValueChanged);
  }
}
```

Now in that event you can do your stuff
But is it required that for every index change you would be hitting the database?