# DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and DataGridViewComboBoxColumn events handling

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form which has a tab control. Each tab has one data gridview. I would get either a combo box values (array of strings) or a text box value (single string) from the database. Based on the values I am creating either `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`  or `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` dynamically and adding it to the datagridview.

Now I want to handle the events of all the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in the data gridview in each tab. I want to know how to handle this situation and any sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: use cellvalidating event

Answer (score 0):

See

[How to bind DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a OnChange event (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827182/how-to-bind-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-to-a-onchange-event-c)

Handle the DataGridView's EditControlShowing event

```
gridview.EditingControlShowing += DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(eventHandlerMethod)
```

then in the eventHandlerMethod handle the object according to it's type, whether that be combobox or text box:

```
    void eventHandlerMethod(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {

        }
        else if (e.Control is TextBox)
        {

        }
    }
```